# How do you instantiate the LinkedListNode shown in my Java code?

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm new to coding, and I'm studying Linked Lists in Java. The code below shows two classes. One class reverses a singly linked list called `ReverseASinglyLinkedList` class, and the other class is a `LinkedListNode` class. I'm having problems with writing the code that tests if my code actually works. In main, I want to pass the following `LinkedList`: `[7, 14, 21, 28]`. I want the code to return `[28, 21, 14, 7]`. First, how would I pass `[7, 14, 21, 28]` into main? I attempted to write the code, but it has errors. I feel that I'm missing something simple, but I'm almost there. Thanks.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedListNode list = new LinkedListNode();
    list.head = new LinkedListNode(7);
    list.head.next = new LinkedListNode(14);
    list.head.next.next = new LinkedListNode(21);
    list.head.next.next.next = new LinkedListNode(28);
    System.out.println(list.data);
    System.out.println("Given Linked list");
    list.printList(list.head);
    list.head = reverse_iterative(list.head);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Reversed linked list ");
    list.printList(list.head);
}

public class LinkedListNode {
    public LinkedListNode next, prev, last;
    public int data;

    public LinkedListNode(int d, LinkedListNode n, LinkedListNode p) {
        data = d;
        setNext(n);
        setPrevious(p);
    }

    public LinkedListNode(int d) {
        data = d;
    }

    public LinkedListNode() {
    }

    public void setNext(LinkedListNode n) {
        next = n;
        if (this == last) {
            last = n;
        }
        if (n != null && n.prev != this) {
            n.setNext(this);
        }
    }

    public void setPrevious(LinkedListNode p) {
        prev = p;
        if (p != null && p.next != this) {
            p.setNext(this);
        }
    }

    public LinkedListNode clone() {
        LinkedListNode next2 = null;
        if (next != null) {
            next2 = next.clone();
        }
        LinkedListNode head2 = new LinkedListNode(data, next2, null);
        return head2;
    }
}

public class ReverseASinglyLinkedList {
    public static LinkedListNode reverse_iterative(
            LinkedListNode head) {
        // no need to reverse if head is null
        // or there is only 1 node.
        if (head == null ||
                head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }

        LinkedListNode list_to_do = head.next;
        LinkedListNode reversed_list = head;

        reversed_list.next = null;

        while (list_to_do != null) {
            LinkedListNode temp = list_to_do;
            list_to_do = list_to_do.next;

            temp.next = reversed_list;
            reversed_list = temp;
        }

        return reversed_list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the surrounding `LinkedList`? Instantiating nodes by itself does not make much sense.

Comment: I guess that's most of my confusion. I want to create a LinkedList with the following entries[7, 14, 21,28].  The following code is my attempt at coding this in main:                                               
     LinkedListNode n = new LinkedListNode(7,new LinkedListNode(14, new LinkedListNode(21, new LinkedListNode(28))));

Comment: That statement is logically wrong, since the *previous* of the entry with value 14 **has to be** the element with value 7, since its next is the one with value 14. Create one note after the other and then call the "correct" `setNext` and `setPrevious` methods.

Comment: How is this looking?            public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListNode n = new LinkedListNode(7);
        LinkedListNode n1 = new LinkedListNode(14);
        LinkedListNode n2 = new LinkedListNode(21);
        LinkedListNode n3 = new LinkedListNode(28);
        n.setNext(n1);
        n1.setNext(n2);
        n2.setNext(n3);
        
        System.out.println(n);
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

Comment: thanks for all your help -luk2302. I updated my main function, but I do get an error with the following line of code:

Comment: The code works now -luk2302. Thanks for your great support. Is there a simpler way to write my main? Anyhow, it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion.
You can create a Node class with data members `Data`, and `previous` and `next` `Node`(often called "pointers" to previous and next Node).
Then create a class called List where you have the data  member as a Node instance and have functions like Insert and reverse and so on where you perform operations on the list.
This is how you can implement it:

```
 class LList{
    private class Node{
        private int data;
        private Node previous;
        private Node next;
        Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = this.previous = null;
        }
    }
    private Node head;
    LList(){
        this.head = null;
    }
    public void insertAtFront(int data){
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        temp.next = head;
        temp.previous = null;
        if(this.head!= null)this.head.previous = temp;
        this.head = temp;
    }
    void reverse() {
        Node temp = null;
        Node current = this.head;

        while (current != null) {
            temp = current.previous;
            current.previous = current.next;
            current.next = temp;
            current = current.previous;
        }

        if (temp != null) {
            this.head = temp.previous;
        }
    }
    public  void printList(Node temp){
        while(temp!=null){
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public Node returnNode(){
        return this.head;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LList var1 = new LList();
    int[] a = {10,20,30,40};
    for(int k : a)var1.insertAtFront(k); //List will look like 40->30->20->10 
    var1.printList(var1.returnNode());
    var1.reverse();
    var1.printList(var1.returnNode());
}
```

Also, your implementation looks like a doubly linked list since you have next and previous "pointers".

This the original code that I wrote :

```
public class LinkedListSO_1_7_2018 {
    static class LList{
        private static class Node{
            // same thing as that of the above
            Node(int data){
               //just like before
            }
        }
        private Node head;
        LList(){
            //same thing 
        }
        public void insertAtFront(int data){
           //same thing
        }
        void reverse() {
            //same thing
        }
        public  void printList(Node temp){
            //and again
        }
        public Node returnNode(){
            //and again
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LList var1 = new LList();
        int[] a = {10,20,30,40};
        for(int k : a)var1.insertAtFront(k);
        var1.printList(var1.returnNode());
        var1.reverse();
        var1.printList(var1.returnNode());

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Shankhadeep Ghoshal. I guess my implementation is a doubly linked list. I love your solution.

Comment: Well, if you google around then this is kind of like how you would find a linked lists. Pretty standard procedures once you have enough practice. Good luck!

Comment: Shankhadeep, when I run your code, I get an error on the following line of code in main 
    LList var1 = new LList();   (ERROR: non-static variable. this cant be referenced from a static context) Any guidance?

Comment: Actually, the LList class is inside another class(the main function's class) and that's why I used static.

Comment: Gotcha. It makes so much more sense to me know. Great work Shankhadeep! Your code works great for me now.

Comment: Also, as an additional resource you should try the book called "Introduction to Algorithms". It will help you understand basic concepts. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, Shankhadeep!!! Who is the author or the "Introduction to Algorithms" book? I really appreciate all of your great direction.

Comment: [Here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) you go. Good luck!

Comment: Great! I'm going to order this book ASAP.